# Transforming infinite series into a function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image: Two questions about infinite series.]

How does one arrive at the answers shown in the image above? For #7 I have been told the sum is equal to $\frac{1-x}{(x-1)(x^2)}$, and recognize that the $(x-1)^{n-1}$ portion is indicative of it being a geometric series since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ar^{n-1}=\frac{a}{1-r}$. However, I can't figure out how to use this to get to the aforementioned function. I have a similar problem with #6, as I can't discern how to find an equivalent function to the sum given. Some final context: this is for AP Calculus BC i.e. high school math and so I'd appreciate answers that don't require college-level analysis. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens when you take the derivative, term-by-term, of the first series, which *is* a geometric series?

Comment: @RobertShore Ah, I get it, it's $\frac{1}{x}$ because it's the derivative of the Taylor series of $\ln{x}$! And that's how you also get the answer to #7, since it's just one derivative further. My problem was not knowing said Taylor series. Regarding the secondary problems, how would you solve them analytically instead of graphically? Namely $\frac{1}{x}=e^x$ and $\frac{1-x}{(x-1)(x^2)}=e^x$. It's beyond the scope of my class, so this is just for curiosity's sake. I suspect the former can be solved through application of the Lambert W function, but I don't know how to go about the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you do not need to "know" the Taylor series of $\ln x.$ For example, since
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nr^n=-\frac{r}{r+1} \tag{1},$$
for $|r|<1,$ it follows that, for $|x-1|<1$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(x-1)^n=\frac{1-x}{x} \tag{2}$$
and taking the derivative of both sides of $(2)$ gives
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nn(x-1)^{n-1}=-\frac{1}{x^2}<0 \tag{3}.$$
For problem $6$, just manipulate $(1)$ accordingly, as you have done so already.

Comment: I understand how (2) and (3) are derived from (1) but don't get how we justify it; from my understanding, wouldn't (1) go as follows? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}r^{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-r)^{n}=\frac{1}{1+r}$

Comment: I think you're confusing $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^{n-1}$ with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^{n}$. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^{n-1}=1+r+r^2+...=\frac{1}{1-r}$, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^{n}=r+r^2+r^3+...=\frac{1}{1-r}-1=\frac{r}{1-r}.$

Comment: That's absolutely what I was stuck on, this clears up everything; thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help!